# What is that meaning of $testModule =~ s@/@::@ig; in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I am a newbie of perl and I'm reading some perl codes, I find one line below I could't understand, can anyone tell what is the meaning of

```
s@/@::@ig
```

I know `=~` is try to match some regular expression. usually I would see code like `s/<regular express>//gi`, so I was a little confused of the following code. can anyone help to elaborate?

```
$testModule =~ s@/@::@ig;
```

Comment: See [Leaning Toothpick Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome).

Comment: If I saw that in a code review I would advise to use `s{/}{::}ig` or `s(/)(::)ig` or even `s!/!::!ig` instead because the `@`s might break syntax highlighting and because it's really unusual to do that.

Answer (score 6):

You can use lots of different characters as regex delimiters.

This one is using `@` instead of `/` so it can use `/` as data inside the regex without escaping it.

It's equivalent to:

```
$testModule =~ s/\//::/ig;
```

See [quote and quote-like operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) in the Perl documentation for more details.