# Perl regex with pipes

Tags: regex, perl

I'm not exactly a perl monk, so if you could help me digest what does this regex(if it is one) do?

```
my $pathHere = "/some/path/to/file";
my $pathThere = "/some/path/";
$pathHere =~ s|$pathThere||;
```

Perl is not exactly my everyday tool, so I am quite shy on knowledge - I guess it subs the match to the var value, but guessing is not the way to go - the pipes throw me off...

Thanks

Comment: pipes are delimiters. We can't use `/` as delimiters because the variable `$pathThere` contains forward slashes. So we go for an another delimiter, say `|` or `~`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813002/what-is-that-meaning-of-testmodule-s-ig-in-perl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Perl you'd normally use the / as a delimiter in the regexp.

```
$pathHere =~ s/abc/def/;   # replace 'abc' with 'def'
```

However you can see that for paths, that's problematic, since you'd have to escape everything.

```
$pathHere =~ s/my\/path\/here/my\/newpath\/there/;
```

Consequently Perl allows you to specify a different delimiter as the character after the 's', hence:

```
$pathHere =~ s|my/path/here|my/newpath/there|;
```

See [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) for more information.

Comment: I was looking for something like that. I will amend appropriately. Thank you