# How to escape forward slashes inside of a bash variable in perl regex?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, perl

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
code=$(</dev/stdin)
prefix="$2"
code=$(perl -p -e "s/\"/\"$prefix/" <<< "$code");
```

It takes something like `#include "myLib.h"` and turns it into `#include  "(some_prefix)myLib.h"`, however, if I input something with a forward slash, like `./script.h -d lib/ < code.txt`, I get an error:

> syntax error at -e line 1, at EOF
> Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

Is there a way of escaping the backslash in the variable `$prefix`?

Comment: use regex with pipe like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31830613/perl-regex-with-pipes

Comment: Please unaccept my answer, per @Wiktor Stribiżew's comment.

Answer (score 0):

you could use pipes in your regex like in stackoverflow.com/questions/31830613/perl-regex-with-pipes

```
code=$(</dev/stdin)
prefix="$2"
code=$(perl -p -e "s|$prefix|" <<< "$code");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you make a regular expression out of user input, you need to escape it for regular expression. Merely changing the delimiter may be not enough, since some characters with special value in regular expression can be legitimately used in a filepath.
Therefore:

```sh
code=$(</dev/stdin)
prefix=$(printf %s "$2" | sed 's/[][()\.^$?*+/]/\\&/g')
code=$(perl -p -e "s/\"/\"$prefix/" <<< "$code");
```

The second line prepends `\` before `][()\.^$?*+/`.

**UPD** per @Wiktor Stribiżew; however you form the replacement string with user input, not the regex (as I imagined), so you need to replace there only the delimiter; and could just as well change the delimiter.

Comment: I like this solution. Thank you.

Comment: You seem to mix replacement and regex metacharacters. In a replacement pattern, only `$` and ``\`` are special.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, yes.